# Flutter issue: Pass argument to Widget constructor as named parameter

Tags: flutter, parameters, named

Flutter issue.  I'm trying to pass an argument to a Widget constructor as a named parameter, but I get the error: The named parameter 'uri' isn't defined.  The code where I define the class is below, followed by the code where I instantiate the Widget. I'm stuck. Any help is much appreciated!

```
//Code defining Widget

class VideoPlayerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  VideoPlayerApp({this.uri});
  final Text uri;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Player Demo',
      home: VideoPlayerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

//Code defining sURI and then instantiating Widget
Text sURI = Text(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4');



onPressed: () {
   Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) => VideoPlayerApp(uri: sURI),
      ),
   );
},
```

Comment: Hi, you need to add the rest of the code for anyone to understand whats happening. 
The above code doesn't tell in whats the scope of sURI and the onPressed() method

Comment: Changing the type from Text to String worked just fine!  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define `uri` as `String`, not `Text`.

Try this:

```
class VideoPlayerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  VideoPlayerApp({
    Key key,
    this.uri,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String uri;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Player Demo',
      home: VideoPlayerScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed My problem.  Thank you so much!  But I still wonder why you can't use Text?